# MVP - hide view methods from client code

Tags: java

While using the Model-View-Presenter pattern I often find myself in the following scenario:

```
// PACKAGE A
// pacakge private
interface View
{
    void methodForPresenter();
}

public class ViewImpl implements View
{
    @Override
    public void methodForPresenter() {}

    public void methodForClient() {}
}

// PACKAGE B
// client code example
void main()
{
    ViewImpl view = new ViewImpl();
    view.methodForClient(); // ok
    view.methodForPresenter(); // not ok - should not be used
}
```

Is there a way how to keep methods meant for presenter hidden inside the package? The view interface is package private for a reason, but since all overriden interface methods in java have to be public, I don't know how to hide the `methodForPresenter()` from the client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution using an anonymous inner class and composition:

```
// PACKAGE A
// pacakge private
interface View
{
    void methodForPresenter();
}

public class ViewImpl
{
    private m_view = new View()
    {
        @Override
        public void methodForPresenter() {}
    }

    public void methodForClient() {}
}

// PACKAGE B
// client code example
void main()
{
    ViewImpl view = new ViewImpl();
    view.methodForClient(); // ok
    view.methodForPresenter(); // now an error
}
```

Now I pass `m_view` to Presenter instead of `this`.